# asp.net global resources problem

Tags: asp.net, resources, global

I have a weird problem with  global resources in my asp.net mvc web application. I have some resources in separate project(not a web app project). Those resources have following settings: Build action: Embedded Resource, Copy To Output Directory: Do not copy, Custom Tool: ResXFileCodeGenerator.   When I change an  existing value in resource file, build solution in release mode and upload neccesary dll files back to server, the previous values in resources are still shown. However, when I add a new key into resource file, the value of this key is shown properly. I do not have this problem during debugging on localhost. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem! I checked the resource files on the production server (with notepad), and it was updated, but ASP.NET ignored the updated values (while recognizing the new values).
I resolved the problem deleting App_GlobalResources and copying it again.
It seems to me that if I overwrite App_GlobalResources (or its content) ASP.NET doesn't update previous values; if I delete it (or its content) then ASP.NET knows to rebuild all information.
I don't understand where ASP.NET store this information ...